# Android Action Bar theme

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Titanium" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

How can i customize my ActionBar component using theme.xml. I tried to generate these files and did place in my `platform/android/res folder`, but no luck

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=ActionBar&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=ffffff%2C100&secondaryColor=1f6e0d%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=fafffb%2C100

Comment: which android platform are you working on and are you using Android Default ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: I am using Android Default ActionBar.

Comment: Did you add the style in your manifest file as the below answerer said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like that :

```
  <style name="CustomStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ANY_DRAWABLE</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        ...
        <item name="PARAM">VALUE</item>
  </style>
```

In CustomActionBar style you can set ActionBar params. In your Activities use CustomStyle.

**UPDATE :**  You can use CustomStyle in Manifest for all Application. Just do it :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomStyle">
```

Or use for each Activity :

```
 <activity
     android:name="MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/CustomStyle">
```

Good luck!

Comment: How to use this CustomStyle in Manifest.xml

Comment: android:theme="@style/CustomStyle" did you try it?

Comment: @Ilya Demidov
 Please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304560/how-to-use-theme-for-searchview-to-override-default-in-titanium please suggest me in this

Answer (score 1):

You should add Theme in your manifest after placement in `<yourproject>/res/*` :

```
<!-- ... -->

<application
    android:name="app.package"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">

<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using : `android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`, try to use `android:style/Theme.Holo` instead and set your theme in manifest file as throrin19 suggest.