# Titanium Android Action Bar theme

Tags: android, tabs, themes, titanium, titanium-mobile

Im using SDK 3.0 and with the xml down here I can change the tabs into Holo Dark theme. Is it possible to change fontsize, because the one I get gives me a swipeable tabBar? And can I get the color pink instead of the blue one?

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Edit: I tried to follow this exampel: [Android Action Bar theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158772/android-action-bar-theme) But i can't get it to work. Otherwise this is exectly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to customize your ActionBar Theme. The tool gives you all resources you need within a "res"-folder. Just copy that folder to `platform/android` beneath your application's root project directory.

In your custom Manifest or directly in the tiapp.xml you refer to that theme by its name:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <manifest>
       <application android:theme="@style/Theme.myCustomActionBarTheme" />
   </manifest>
</android>
```

This solution works very fine for me - and I hope it helps!

Comment: I get a lot of errors. [ERROR] /Users/hugocarlmartin/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/kattproblem-an
droid/build/android/res/values/styles_mycustomstyle.xml:21: error: Error retriev
ing parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:sty
le/Theme.Holo'.
[ERROR] /Users/hugocarlmartin/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/kattproblem-an
droid/build/android/res/values/styles_mycustomstyle.xml:22: error: Error: No res
ource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarItemBackground'.
and so on....

Comment: Have you replaced the name of the theme with exactly the same name that you entered in the style generator?
Also make sure the platform/android/res/ directory in the root directory of your project?

Comment: I dont need the theme.xml in /values right? What Ti SDK are you on?

Comment: You don't need to create another file inside of res/ ... just copy the whole folder into your project. When you take a look into /res/values/styles.xml the first style item in the <resources> will tell you the name of your custom theme (created by Style Generator).
You should use this name in your custom manifest to refer to that theme `<application android:theme="@style/Theme.myCustomActionBarTheme" />`

Comment: Thank you so much, in the generator i name it with camelstyle. But in the styles.xml it was small letters. Works perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to support an Action Bar on all platforms. It provides huge custom styling opportunities. I changed the blue separator to a green one. Here's my xml:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenAB"></application>
```

/res/values/abs_green_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.GreenAB" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_style</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/green_style</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

/res/drawable/green_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Green Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF177506" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of the action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you don't need support on all platforms you might even use this without third-party libraries. Replace the parent theme (Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow) with an Android resource and remove the duplicate item entries in the style sections.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about how to use a custom Holo Theme in Titanium Mobile: http://blog.rafaelks.com/post/47898772164/how-to-use-custom-holo-theme-in-android-with-titanium.

It's similar to **manumaticx** answer.